# OrderFront - NSPanel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, window

I have this code:

```
[hudWindow orderFront:nil];
```

`hudWindow` is a NSPanel.

When I debug it and run, the command does not seem to work. I don't get any error messages in the console, and the HUD Window doesn't appear when I call it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "does not seem to work"? What does the panel do, and what does it not do that you expect it to?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console? Are there any messages in the status bar of Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you hooked up the `hudWindow` outlet in IB. If you didn't, the outlet variable contains `nil`, so you're sending a message to `nil`, which does nothing.